# How to fill data in textbox when open modal in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hello I got data in json format in codeigniter using ajax so when i open modal how to get data in text box

here is my query:

```
public function assign_password()
{
    $id = $this->input->POST('employee_id');

    $query = $this->db->query("Select * from account_registration WHERE aid='$id'")->result_array(); 
    echo json_encode($query); 


}
```

HERE IS MY AJAX CALL:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.assign_pass', function(){  
    var employee_id = $(this).attr("id");  
    $.ajax({  
        url:"<?php echo base_url('welcome/assign_password')?>",  
        method:"POST",  
        data:{employee_id:employee_id},  
        dataType:"json",  
        success:function(data){ 
            var emp = $('#employee_name').val(data.firstname); 
            console.log(emp); 
            $('#add_data_Modal').modal('show');  
        }  
    });  
});
```

Comment: use `->row_array();` instead of `->result_array();` if you need to return single result. Else you need loop in javascript side.

Comment: yes it is working